# Multiple instances of nested uploaded files - need help on this design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, model, nested, uploader

I've been going around in circles on this.

I have a Job and the Job has multiple Tasks.  Each Task has one input File and one output File. There is one model for a File.  An input File may be used in multiple tasks.  Each task has a single output File.  (I'm using jQuery Upload for the files.)

Ideally, I want a nested relationship of  Job -> Task -> File, however the unique relationship is one input File and one output File per Task, so logically the Task has a couple if File_ids in the model and the Task belongs to each File, but then the nesting is backwards and none of the standard form relationships work.

I've looked at join models with has_one_through and at polymorphism, but nothing quite lines up.  Between the single input File serving multiple Tasks, and the File model referenced in two roles within the Task, I haven't come up with an obvious solution.

Suggestions???

----------- Addendum ----------

I use Cocoon for many things, but here, on a Job form, a file upload (using jQuery Upload) creates a new File and builds its parent, a Task, all in the create section of the File controller, then adds them to the form via javascript.

Trying to clarify, a File is a child of a Task in one of two roles (input or output).  A File can also be a child of several other models not mentioned above.  If a File were always a child of only one parent, then polymorphism would be a good solution.  What causes problems is that in one instance (input for a Task) one File might serve as the child for more than one parent (Task).  As pixelearth noted, this will need to be a join table.  Perhaps, since 'Task input' is the only multiple case, I should implement this one with a join (has_many :through) and use polymorphism for the rest.  I was hoping for a single solution without either a lot of join tables or a lot of foreign keys in File.

Comment: i'm not sure exactly what you trying to achieve. but I know [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo/tree/master/app/views/projects) is great when it comes to nested forms. it has some good examples too. Also checkout [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested_form) nested_form episodes to get a perspective. But cocoon gem does a great job

Answer (score 0):

If your input file can be used for more than one task, then you will need a join model (and table) and you'll have to use a has_one :through. If the output file also can belong_to many tasks, you'll need to use a has_many :through, or define both as has_one :(output|input)_file :through and a scope on the what constitutes a which type using :conditions

There's no way around using a join model if they can relate to multiple tasks. A file couldn't just have a task_id since there would be multiple tasks. If there were a limit on the number of tasks it could belong to, then you could use multiple fields task_1_id, task_2_id, etc. But that would be an abomination.